# Understanding Windows share deny permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list

I am developing some reporting for a series of Windows shares and I am not clear on the implementation details regarding permissions with deny types. While trying to calculate the resulting effective mask a user is subjected to after compensating for all share and ntfs permissions, it is not clear to me how to accomodate a deny type if present at the share level.

According to [Permissions on a Shared Folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783530(v=ws.10)), the more restrictive permission takes precedence between the share and ntfs permissions and a deny type at the share level supersedes any permission at the ntfs level.

Consider the case where *user-a* has an explicit grant for `Full Control` at both the share and ntfs level.

If a group which *user-a* is a member of is added to the shares acl, any combination of a deny, `Read`, `Change` or `Full Control` manifests as no access at all for *user-a*. In addition, with the group set to `Read` on the share permission, *user-a* cannot delete a file if the path is known programmatically.

Effectively, if the context accessing a share acquires a deny of any mask, all access is denied based on my tests.

What is the use case for three mask options with a deny when the least restrictive (read) prevents all access entirely? I am aware that you can set finer grained permissions programmatically, however why expose even 3 from the UI when they all behave the same?

Comment: `What is the use case for three mask options with a deny when the least restrictive (read) prevents all access`. There isn't a use case.

Comment: There most certainly has to be a valid reason for this misleading implementation detail, I would love to know it. Feel free to write this up as an answer and thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Share Permissions and NTFS permissions come from different areas of thinking. Share permissions existed before NTFS came along, and are included for backwards compatibility with older Drive Formats (fat, fat32). As far as I am personally aware, if you have NTFS permissions, share permissions are set to Everyone and full access. NTFS permissions will then apply without any quirks.

Comment: @Stese, it can sometimes be useful to have two shares pointing at the same directory, one of which is read-write and the other read-only.  Also, setting the share permissions to "change" rather than "full control" can be a convenient way to prevent people messing with the file permissions, even for files they own.

Comment: The reason there are three separate "deny" checkboxes is probably just that Microsoft wanted to use the user interface that already existed for file permissions, rather than trying to design and implement a new one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston :-  Setting advanced NTFS permissions to prevent permissions changes will also do that... Share and NTFS permissions are not meant to co-exist... which is what MS has always taught on their on certifications. Also, users should only 'own' files within their own profile folders, if roaming profiles are in use. Any files on other network shares should always been owned by the admin. This prevents all kinds of problems down the line.

Comment: @Stese, NTFS permissions, by design, cannot prevent someone changing the permission on a file they own.  And since ownership of a file created by a non-admin user is always given to that user, I don't see any way to prevent them changing the permissions on files they created other than at the share level.  This is an edge case, though, as a general rule you don't want to do this - in particular, there are applications that will fail to function properly if they can't change permissions on their document files.

Comment: ... my point is just that combining share and NTFS permissions works perfectly well, and can sometimes be useful.  Any recommendation to avoid it is probably just because it sometimes confuses novice sysadmins.  There's definitely no problem from a technological perspective.

Comment: Users only become owners of files and folders they create if the user is given Full Control. This is not required in most cases, and again, using Modify is what Microsoft themselves recommend. Full Control & Ownership on files is only required for User Profile files and folders.

Comment: @Stese, *Users only become owners of files and folders they create if the user is given Full Control.* - uh, that's not true.  I've just double-checked, and even if I only have Modify permission to the folder, when I create a file, I'm the owner.

Comment: I've done similar tests and its behaved that way for me... can't explain that...